# Using classes in Django models

Tags: python, django

I have a model which has a large number of sub fields that seem like they ought to be proceedurally generated:

```
class evaluation(models.Model):
    factor1high = models.IntegerField(verbose_name="Factor 1 High Estimate")
    factor1med = models.IntegerField(verbose_name="Factor 1 Mid. Estimate")
    factor1low = models.IntegerField(verbose_name="Factor 1 Low Estimate")
    factor1comment = models.TextField()
    factor2high = models.IntegerField(verbose_name="Factor 2 High Estimate")
    ...
    factor15mid = models.IntegerField(verbose_name="Factor 15 Mid. Estimate")
    factor15low = models.IntegerField(verbose_name="Factor 15 Low Estimate")
    factor15comment = models.textField()
```

What I would like to do is break this down into two classes, similar to this:

```
classs factor(models.Model):
    high = models.IntegerField(verbose_name="High Estimate")
    med  = models.IntegerField(verbose_name="Mid. Estimate")
    low  = models.IntegerField(verbose_name="Low Estimate")
    comment = models.TextField()
    name = models.textField()

class evaluation(models.Model):
    factors = [
        factor(name = "Factor 1"),
        factor(name = "Factor 2"),
        ...
        factor(name = "Factor 15")
    ]
```

This of course does not work in Django.  It seems like something along these lines ought to be possible though.

So far, I've tried:

- use ForeignKey to relate factors: Kind of works, but I have to use the reverse lookup on the factor_set to get the factors, which is suboptimal, and there is no easy way to preconstruct the factors with their unique names. Also does not render nicely in a form without a lot of custom handlers and such.
- use OneToOne to connect factors: Functional, but breaks all of Django's nice integrated form construction and management stuff. There is no easy way to dereference all the factors to iterate through them.

The only option I have come up with that works is to just create all the fields by hand, which leads to lots of duplication of effort, which seems counter to Django's DRY principle. I also really want to be able to add additional parameters to a factor in the future without having to go through and add them in for each factor one at a time.

It seems like there ought to be a way to do this, I just have been unable to find it.

Comment: I believe The standard way to model this in django is to include a ForeignKey in `factor` class back to `evaluation` as you have already tried, When you create an evaluation you can create the 15 associated factors.  What is suboptimal about the reverse lookup? What are you trying to achieve, and how is the reverse lookup failing?

Comment: @dm03514 Several things about that solution cause problems. First, when I use a `ModelForm` to generate a default form, it doesn't contain the `factor`s. So, now I have to put an entry for each `factor` in the form, which just moves the work around. Second, there is no good way (that I know of) to automatically create the 15 or so `factor`s. I have to do that by hand whenever I create an `evaluation`. I want to tie this creation permanently to the creation of an `evaluation` so that I don't risk forgetting to instantiate all the factors every time.

Comment: I'm not quite sure what to do about the ModelForm but for the Factor creation, you could override create method, or create a static method that creates x factors

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best solution to this problem I came up with was to create a custom `FactorField`, which contains all the bits of information called out in the original question. This also allows the option to associate a custom widget for displaying the data in a meaningful way.

I found [this webpage](http://tothinkornottothink.com/post/10815277049/django-forms-i-custom-fields-and-widgets-in-detail) to be helpful in creating the custom objects.

Answer (score 0):

You could dynamically create a certain number of factors when an evaluation is created:

```
class Evaluation(models.Model):
   @classmethod
   def create(cls, num_factors):
       evaluation = cls()
       evaluation.save()
       for i in range(1, num_factors + 1):
           factor(name='Factor: {}'.format(i), evaluation=evaluation)
```

Comment: This still leaves me in the same issue discussed earlier when it comes time to display this information in a form.